# Could we have an indication on up-/downvotes received for meta questions/answers in the navbar?

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta, top-bar

I've just got a notification, that I earned the [mortarboard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=1413395) badge on meta, but I can't track which questions/answers were involved, since meta up-/downvotes aren't tracked at all. Is there a simple way to see which questions/answers lead to this?

**Feature request to be discussed:**
Could we have an indication on up-/downvotes received for meta questions/answers in the navbar? (at least when the currently displayed site is *meta*).

Proposal:

[image]

Comment: I suspect only SEDE can provide this but ain't finding an adequate query. Anyway, it would only work next week when the data is updated.

Comment: Here's the MSE version of this request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167648/make-voting-activity-on-your-posts-available-on-site-metas-what-you-would-get-f

Comment: SEDE queries: [calculate meta rep (uncapped)](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/157285/meta-reputation-classifications) and [days towards Epic and Legendary badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/160805/legendary-badge-advancement-topcount). Data is refreshed every Sunday.

Comment: API-driven page to track Meta votes: http://jsbin.com/ximuhuzo/1